# Would the filter() method gets first priority in the method chain?

Tags: jquery

Assume this method chain

```
$("label").css("color", "blue").add("input[name!='rose']").filter("[for!='snowdrop']").css("font-size", ".75em");
```

In the above method call chain a call to the `filter()` in place. Typically method calling order is first come first serve. But when there is a `filter()` like above would that get called before `add()` method?

Comment: Javascript methods are always called in order.

Comment: @SLaks ok thanks  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when there is a `filter()` like above would that get called before `add()` method?

No, that would be impossible. When you have `a().b().c()`, what's happening is that `a` is called, and it returns something; that something's `b` property is called as a function, and returns something; that something's `c` property is called as a function.

So as you can see, `filter` can't be called before `add` in that chain, because `filter` is called on what `add` *returns*.

Comment: hello,, just curious can be situations this order of chain called gets differed ?

Comment: @NPNeilFooty: It doesn't matter which functions you call; Javascript always works the same way.

Comment: @NPNeilFooty: The order will only be different if you arrange the function calls differently.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  thank you it cleared a doubt i had : )